# Keep my work safe in a temporary branch?

Tags: git, branch

I'm working on a new feature in a branch that will eventually be pulled into our master.  In the meantime however there are changes I've made in in my branch that may or not make the final cut--  I'd like to temporarily store this work someplace offline in case my box crashes.

I'm thinking about a temporary branch for all this, checking one out, committing and pushing what I have to it, then checking out my original branch and continuing.

And the next time I want to keep my changes offline-- make another temp branch, or use the same one?  When it comes time to issue a pull request (we're on github) to master, anything special I should do, or just issue from my original branch?

I'm sure there are several ways to do this and am looking for one that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm thinking about a temporary branch for all this, checking one out, committing and pushing what I have to it, then checking out my original branch and continuing.

Nothing wrong with that. Do it.

> And the next time I want to keep my changes offline-- make another temp branch, or use the same one?

Create a new one. There's no harm in that. Just make sure to clean up after yourself,
delete the junky branches on the server after you don't need them anymore.

> When it comes time to issue a pull request (we're on github) to master, anything special I should do, or just issue from my original branch?

Nothing special to do. You can issue pull request from the temporary branch too.

Comment: You could also use `git stash` as an *anonymous* branch.  Remember you can provide a 'name' when you stash.  This becomes a label to reference the set of changes later.

Comment: The OP wants to avoid losing data due to crash of the work PC. To avoid that, OP wants to push to server.